# python regex: skip word

Tags: python, regex

I use regular expressions a fair bit in python and I a bit stumped on a seemingly easy problem. 
I am trying to match a string of the form:

```
output    wire     some_net,
```

Now, the word wire may be there or it may not be. I also want to capture the words output (could also be input)  and some_net (a variable word)
So, if we have the format:

```
output    wire     some_net,
```

I wish to capture `output` and `some_net`,

But if we have the format:

```
output        some_net,
```

I still wish the string to match `output` and `some_net` to be captured.

The regular expression I was trying was this:

```
re.compile(ur'^\s*(?P<io>output|input)\s+(?:wire\s+|\s+)(?P<net>\w+)', re.U),
```

But it doesn't work, it captures the word `wire` in the test string:

```
output    wire [2:0]                some_net,               // some comment
```

In fact, I don't want a match at all for the above test string (I have a different regex to deal with this.

So, is there a way to cater for this kind of situation?

Comment: are you parsing a verilog file?

Comment: @PYPL I am indeed! I am writing a little script to diff port listings in the verilog file to ensure they match

Comment: @AvinashRaj I don't understand your comment. I am aware that a [ is not a word character. The [2:0] in the test string isn't in all the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pattern = re.match("^\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+\s*(\S+)?)?\s+(\S+),.*", verilogString)
```

testing with `wire` in string

```
Input String: 
   output    wire     some_net,
Out:
   pattern.group(1) = 'output'
   pattern.group(4) = 'some_net'
```

without `wire` in string

```
Input String:
   output    some_net,
Out:
   pattern.group(1) = 'output'
   pattern.group(4) = 'some_net'
```

Testing with wire range

```
Input String:
   output    wire [2:0]                some_net,               // some comment
Out:
   pattern.group(1) = 'output'
   pattern.group(4) = 'some_net'
```

Comment: This is great, thanks PYPL! The regex I ended up using is: `re.compile(ur'^\s*(?P<io>output|input)(?:\s+(?P<net>\w+))+\s*[,/$]', re.U)` The key feature that I hadn't considered was using variable amounts of a capturing group.The final script has been shared here: https://gist.github.com/mentaal/efa142af28492acd2ed9

Comment: @GregoryKuhn hmm can't use your regex on the last case with wire range, take a look: https://www.regex101.com/r/oF5jW6/1

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Ya, this is perfect, I am not smart enough to cover a ranged port listing and a single net in one regex so I have a different regex for the ranged example that you have in your linked test. You can can see both in the gist in the previous comment if you're interested. I'm actually counting on this regex to fail for a ranged listing. This script seems to work for me now.